# Yii2 How to display a single record from a related model's gridview

Tags: model-view-controller, yii2, foreign-key-relationship

I have two tables, 'employee' and 'employee_payrecords'.

I have a view called 'dashboard' that is based on the Employee model.  Employee is related to employee_payrecords (n:m).  On the dashboard, I have a gridview widget that shows all payrecords.  I would like to be able to click on 'view' (in the action column of the Gridview widget) for the payrecord, and display the payrecord in a new window (1 payrecord).  Currently if I hover over the payrecord's 'view' action it displays the correct id of the payrecord in the browser's bottom preview bar but if I click on the 'view' action item it gives me a 'Not Found' error.  I just simply want to display the payrecord in it's own view.  What am I missing?

**In the EmployeeController**, I have an action to view paycheck from the EmployeePayrecord model (which is related via the Employee model):

```
public function actionViewPaycheck($id)
{
    $model = EmployeePayrecord::findOne($id);

    return $this->render('viewPaycheck', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

**In the Employee model** I have a method to retreive all payrecords (for the Gridview in 'dashboard' view):

```
public function getEmployeePayrecords()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\frontend\models\EmployeePayrecord::className(), ['employee_id' => 'id']);
}
```

And **in the 'dashboard' view** I have created what I think is the correct URL as previously mentioned above, it does display the correct record number for the payrecord in the browser's preview of the link (before I click the 'view' action button.) Also, not shown here is the view-paycheck view (viewPaycheck.php) which is what the url refers to, to display the payrecord:

```
[
     'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
     'template' => '{view}',
     'header' => 'Actions',
     'buttons' => [
           'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                return Html::a(
                   '<span>view</span>',
                   ['employee/view-paycheck', 'id' => $model->id],
                   ['title' => Yii::t('app', 'View Paycheck')]
                 );
             }
      ],
],
```

Action rendering Dashboard view:

```
public function actionDashboard($id)
{
    /**
     * Use the employee layout for 'dashboard'
     */
    $this->layout = 'employee';

    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    $providerEmployeePayrecords = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $model->employeePayrecords,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 5,
        ]
    ]);

    return $this->render('dashboard', [
        'model' => $model,
        'providerEmployeePayrecords' => $providerEmployeePayrecords,

    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using this in one button only there is no point of modifying whole urlCreator.

```
[
    'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
    'template' => '{view}',
    'header' => 'Actions',
    'buttons' => [
        'view' => function ($url, $model) {
            return Html::a(
                '<span>view</span>', 
                ['employee/view-paycheck', 'id' => $model->id], 
                ['title' => Yii::t('app', 'View Paycheck')]
            );
        }
    ],
],
```

**UPDATE**

After long debugging process we have finally got to the core of the error.

There were two GridViews (Kartik's version) in the view, both using Pjax (through `pjax` setting and not the Pjax wrapper) and apparently second one, which was using different link for the `view` button, has been loaded somehow into the first pjax container, changing the target URL for the button link.

`pjaxSettings` have been set to use different ID for container so it should not be the case but looks like there is a bug with this.

Removing the `pjax` settings from GridViews and using the standard `Pjax` wrapper (`Pjax::begin()` and `Pjax::end()`) helped and fixed the problem.

Comment: Is it "view not found" or "employee payrecord not found"? If you take one of the IDs from your GridView and use it to call `EmployeePayrecord::findOne($id);` do you get result? You must debug this code.

Comment: It's 'Not Found #404'...It is correctly opening the url to: 'employee/view-paycheck?id=1183" and that record exists both in the table and in the gridview but won't display in the view page.  I'm obviously missing something simple.

Comment: Check you view path info (added in answer)

Comment: It is: frontend/views/employee/viewPaycheck.php.  Could this be a problem with the view file itself?  Doesn't seem likely considering I am getting a 404 error.  But when I try to open the view file with an employee_id instead of the actual payrecord id (like employee/view-paycheck?id=1 (the logged in employee's id; not the payrecord id), I am at least getting, 'trying to get property of non-object' error which highlights the $model variable as the error.  Is it trying to load the paycheck through the employee model instead of the EmployeePayrecord model?  And why?

Comment: Is the GriView code with the action column part of the `dashboard` view or `viewPaycheck` view? Maybe there is something in the `EmployeePayrecord` model... Not sure anymore. Could you paste all related controller, views and models to some service like pastebin?

Comment: My apologies for the delay in getting back to you.  I've listed all pertinent information that is in any way related to this issue.  Thanks again for your help.  See the pastebin: http://pastebin.com/iCfkuWNF

Comment: I cannot find any issues there. You need to debug ViewPaycheck action - see if `var_dump` on `$model` shows something interesting. Exact error message would be useful as well.

Comment: I cleared the whole viewPaycheck.php view file and replaced it with var_dump($model) so I could load the page, but the only way I could load the page was if I used the employee id as the parameter (this has to be a clue I would think) as the payrecord's id only returned #404 Not Found error. The var_dump for the employee_id  (employee/view-paycheck?id=1) returned, 'frontend\views\employee\view‌​Paycheck.php:10:null‌​'

Comment: Ok, looks like `UrlManager` issue. Check your URL rules.

Comment: 'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],

Comment: And what do you get with `var_dump($providerEmployeePayrecords->getModels())` in `dashboard` view?

Comment: My last idea - what's in `EmployeePayrecordQuery`?

Comment: @Marko please check in your `employee_payrecords` database table if there is `id` column set as primary key (PK) because I suspect it's not the case.

Comment: Id is set as the primary key on both the employee and employee_payrecords table. I think I discovered the problem but don't know how to fix it. When I look at the log in the debugger, as I suspected and mentioned before, it is trying to pull the payrecord id from the employee table. SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id='1178' \frontend\models\EmployeeQuery‌​‌​.php:33 \frontend\controllers\Employee‌​Controller.php:191 \frontend\controllers\Employee‌​Controller.php:85 1178 is the payrecord id....so apparently the controller's action is not set correctly for the query.

Comment: Please tell me you have got proper database table name set in `tableName()` method of `EmployeePayrecord`...

Comment: Yes it's correct.  It's the query in the actionViewPaycheck that is the problem I'm 99% sure of it.  It's not looking in the EmployeePayrecord model but instead in the Employee model.  I'm certain it's just a matter of figuring out the proper query, which I have yet to do.

Comment: Check it please. I think I could find it yesterday if you post all code, not just the parts.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131791/discussion-on-answer-by-bizley-yii2-how-to-display-a-single-record-from-a-relate).